# External Hard Drive Corrupted, Invalid Record Count

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, fsck

I have an external hard drive that I unplugged without safely ejecting and now it won't mount. I can see it if I write `diskutil list`, but when I try to mount it fails. It is a WD My Passport Ultra.
When I try `sudo fsck_hfs -f /dev/disk4s2` it says the following:

```
** /dev/rdisk4s2
Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.1.3).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
** Detected a case-sensitive volume.
   The volume name is My Passport
** Checking extents overflow file.
** Checking catalog file.
   Invalid record count
(4, 544356)
** The volume My Passport could not be verified completely.
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix this??

Comment: Somehow the catalog got corrupted.  An easy fix is to reformat.  If you have data you wish to preserve, use a utility like [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) or [DiskWarrior](https://alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/)